# How can I make a filter between 2 columns on the same csv file in java?

Tags: java, filter, count

Hello I have a java class that counts all rows from a csv file.
But now I need to create a filter so it only counts a certain amount of rows, depending on the condition in the filter.

Something like this:

```
COUNTROWS(FILTER(Customer_Data, Customer_Data[Age]>=18
&& Customer_Data[IsActiveMember]=1))
```

I am learning java now and this is quite dificult.

My code at the moment:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CountRows {

    public static void countorows() throws IOException {
        var Query ="COUNTROWS(FILTER(Customer_Data, Customer_Data[Age]>=18\r\n"
                + "&& Customer_Data[IsActiveMember]=1))";
      
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(new File("file location"));
        var teste = file.getcustomers();
        System.out.println(teste.size());
    }
}
```

csv file (it has 10.000 lines like this): `

```
RowNumber,CustomerId,Surname,CreditScore,Geography,Gender,Age,Tenure,Balance,NumOfProducts,HasCrCard,IsActiveMember,EstimatedSalary,Exited
1,15634602,Hargrave,619,France,Female,42,2,0,1,1,1,101348.88,1
2,15647311,Hill,608,Spain,Female,41,1,83807.86,1,0,1,112542.58,0
3,15619304,Onio,502,France,Female,42,8,159660.8,3,1,0,113931.57,1
3,15619304,Onio,502,France,Female,42,8,159660.8,3,1,0,113931.57,2
3,15619304,Onio,502,France,Female,42,8,159660.8,3,1,0,113931.57,3
3,15619304,Onio,502,France,Female,42,8,159660.8,3,1,0,113931.57,4
3,15619304,Onio,502,France,Female,42,8,159660.8,3,1,0,113931.57,5
3,15619304,Onio,502,France,Female,42,8,159660.8,3,1,0,113931.57,6
```

Comment: for starters, parsing a query in java and then applying transformations and filters on a data that is in a separate csv file is quite a challenge in java. We would need more information to help you out here. The `ReadFile` class seems to be custom, so when you do `file.getcustomers()` what do you get as a result ( provide a sample ) so that we can start from there to help you out. Also please clarify if you only want to filter out columns or want to create an entire sql like system here?

Comment: file.getcustomers() stores the entire csv file in "teste".  I will add a sample of the csv file in the question

Comment: well and it is someting like a sql system

Comment: Is the CSV file structure constant? Does it always contain the same fields in the same order? For example is the _Age_ field always the seventh field? Does the _Age_ field always follow the _Gender_ field?

Comment: yes the structure is constant

Comment: And is the `Query` variable text that you have to parse and interpret? In other words, the value of `Query` may be different to what appears in your question? It could be, for example: `COUNTROWS(FILTER(Customer_Data, Customer_Data[Gender]=Female))` Also, out of the eight rows in your sample CSV data, six of them have RowNumber=3. Is that a mistake?

Comment: yes the Query value could be different, and the repeated row number is a mistake

Comment: tbh, this problem is quite complicated if you want a custom solution, i would tempted to load all this into a sqlite database and then run the queries as required, ( note that you have mentioned that you have ~10k rows , which implies that any algo that we come up with, might be full of bugs and we might miss a lot of edge cases ). Otherwise, i'd do some research online to see if there are any libraries already in java supporting this functionality that you required, atleast even if the search part is done, then the query parsing bit is something that you should be able to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

the way I know to read files is:

1. open the file.
2. read the file line by line.
3. make a mapping of the retrieved line to the respective fields such as Age, name ...
4. then a filter can be done through an if statement...

maybe you need to do something:

```
public class CountRows {

    public static void countorows() throws IOException {
    
        try {
            int counter = 0;
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new inputFile);
            String readLine = "";
            while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
                String sNewLine = new String(sLinea_nueva.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                String[] sLinea = sNewLine.split(",");
                String sName = sLinea[0];
                String sAge = sLinea[1];
                if (Integer.value(sAge) >= 18) {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```